# .execute во Фрагменте

Tags: java, android

делаю запрос в api в активити и все работает.

```
NetworkTask networkTask = new NetworkTask();
    networkTask.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + currentLatitude + "&lon=" + currentLongitude + "&appid=TAG_KEY");
```

Сейчас перешел во фрагмент где пытаюсь использовать тот же самый код, но у меня выходит ошибка на .execute, что с этим можно сделать ?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему вставкой всего кода в метод  public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {}